# Is there a function to calculate this unit vector in glm?

Tags: c++, glm-math

I have the following function in c++ to calculate a unit vector:

```
glm::vec3 unit_vector(glm::vec3 v) {
    return v / (float)v.length();
}
```

Is there a glm equivalent I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `v.length()` actually returns the number of components of the vector (in this case: `3`) so this function doesn't do what you think it does. There is a `glm` function that changes the magnitude of a vector to `1` (making it a unit vector). This operation is called normalizing. `glm::normalize` can do that.

Your function could be implemented like this:

```
#include <glm/geometry.hpp>

glm::vec3 unit_vector(glm::vec3 v) {
    return glm::normalize(v);
}
```

Or just use `glm::normalize` directly.